# JSON, JAXB,JSON Rest

Tags: json, rest, jaxb, jackson

I created a Rest Service which has is working fine in XML request ( Rest Service input JAXB generated class ). When I am trying to send a Json Request, It's throwing an exception.

```
SEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Transaction] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: 
class Transaction which is inner class .
```

My Request class is generated from schema using JAXB, My getter method is like below but no setter method.

```
public List<Transaction> getORIG() {
        if (origtrans == null) {
            origtrans = new ArrayList<Transaction>();
        }
        return this.origtrans;
    }
```

My Json Request below

```
{
  "LOB_CD": "42424"
  "ORIGINALTRANSACTION" : [
    "LOGON_ID" : "TEST"

  ]
}
```

When I am addiong original Transaction it's throwing an error otherwise it's working fine.

Can you please help me out with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make sure you are using a valid JSON, like:

```
{
    "LOB_CD": "42424",
    "ORIGINALTRANSACTION": {
        "LOGON_ID": "TEST"
    }
}
```

Also, it would be nice if you could show us the **Transaction** class.

Comment: After making those changes, I am getting below error

Comment: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token

Comment: [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@a224b5; line: 11, column: 17] (through reference chain: Transction Class

Comment: Try to put the JSON into an array `[ ... ]`

Comment: I change my JSON into array like before and getting the same error like belowSEVERE: The exception contained within MappableContainerException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class Transaction] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (through reference chain: 
class Transaction which is inner class .

Comment: Change your JSON into this: `[ {
    "LOB_CD": "42424",
    "ORIGINALTRANSACTION": {
        "LOGON_ID": "TEST"
    }
} ]`
Could you post the **Transaction** class?

Comment: Thank you Edwin, It works. I did following steps  1)  Added an empty constructor     2) Added this annotataion for the list @JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=Transaction.class)  3) change a Json Object to   {
  "LOB_CD": "42424"
  "ORIGINALTRANSACTION" : [ {
    "LOGON_ID" : "TEST"
 }
  ]
}

Answer (score 0):

It works. 
I did following steps 
1) Added an empty constructor 
2) Added this annotation for the list

```
@JsonDeserialize(as=ArrayList.class, contentAs=Transaction.class)
```

3) change a Json Object to 
`{ "LOB_CD": "42424" "ORIGINALTRANSACTION" : [ { "LOGON_ID" : "TEST" } ] }`

Thanks a lot,
Patel